# What can cause cyclical CPU spikes on a SQL Server precisely every 5min

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server

## Setup

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 (Yes I know I need to upgrade).
The server is accessed by a single Linux/Apache web server.

## Problem

Starting about a week ago and slowly getting worse a spike in CPU on the database server has occurred every 5min (on the hour%5 minute). This went unnoticed until it started causing the web application to timeout on connections to it a few days ago. We reviewed our Datadog feed and discovered this slowly more aggressive CPU spike.

The CPU spikes are usually 5-10% CPU for about 3seconds. But occasionally jump to 100% and lock the server up completely causing the timeouts. During these 100% spikes the server is locked for about 10sec on the rdp connection and about 1/2 sec for database connections which is just long enough to cause a few ~20 timeouts before being freed up.

Windows task manager confirmed this is caused by the SQL Server Process.

## My Attempts

- The clear pattern makes me think cron job. We only have 1 cron active and it runs at the top of the hour.
- Restarting the database and restarting the server itself changed nothing.
- I ran sql server profiler during one of the spikes and no queries were run during the spikes that would justify them nor was their an excessive number of queries, nor was the disk activity showing an expensive query like it normally would.
- Windows Task Scheduler has nothing at 5min increments.
- Datadog sends every 1 minute and does not access the SQL server process directly.
- Windows logs show no unusual activity on the 5 minute increment.
- Auto-shrink is not turned on, nor do we have any automated SQL tasks except nightly backups. (Yes I know I need to set up index cleanup tasks but I haven't gotten around to it yet.).
- Disk activity does not appear to be affected by the CPU spike.
- No other users are logged into the system. I am using RDP and have nothing running except SQL Server Management Studio.
- The server has no access outside of the network except RDP on a non-standard port.
- Hardware host is reliable/stable and not likely to be a factor.
- I ran sp_WhoIsActive during the spikes and nothing useful was provided. Different databases was active each time, and cpu on the database was not high enough to explain the issue. This and profiler seem to tell me this is process related not database related.

## My Suspicions

I suspect SQL Server is running some kind of background defrag, optimize, index clean, auto-shrink task that is built into the server and running into problems. But I can find no documentation or actual evidence of such a background task existing nor would I know how to verify this.

It may also be possible that some other program is actually causing the issue but is not showing up in task manager, or is being errantly grouped with SQL Server. I don't know how I would identify such a thing.

I am pulling my hair out and have run out of idea on what to look for. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: "*This went unnoticed until it started causing the web application to timeout on connections to it a few days ago*" and "*I ran sql server profiler during one of the spikes and no queries were run during the spikes that would justify them*" - How do you know this is definitively the cause of your web application timeouts? What is the CPU percentage usage at when it spikes? You should use something like [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/) when there's a spike to see everything that's actively running on the server, what resources it's consuming, and what it's waiting on.

Comment: @J.D. The cpu spikes were initially around 10%. They now occasionally jump to 100% locking the server up completely for about 10seconds (rdp) and causing timeouts on connections incoming for about 1/10th of a second. Timeout is 1/2 second. so that means actual server downtime is about 6/10 of a second.

Comment: @J.D. sp_WhoIsActive did not give any useful info. Different databases active each time, none of the active suspicious or consuming enough resources to justify the spike. Of course I can only run it during the smaller spikes as during the larger spikes I lose connectivity.

Comment: Maybe it's [checkpoints](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/common-sql-server-consulting-advice-setting-target-recovery-interval/)?

Comment: Probably nothing to do with SQL Server at all. Either your hard drive is showing its age, or someone has installed some malware on your system. I strongly suspect the former: a hard drive stall can easily cause the whole operating system to freeze. Check SQL Server error logs for FlushCache messages.

Comment: @ErikDarling That is very interesting. However all the literature on this seems to say it's 2012 plus. I am on 2008 still. How do I see what the interval is for 2008 or set it?

Comment: I agree with Charlieface that the cause seems likely to be something outside of your SQL Server instance. An easy way to prove that is by completely shutting down the SQL Server service on that machine, and then monitor the CPU and see if the spikes still occur. If they do, then that's definitive proof it's unrelated to your SQL Server instance. Should be easy enough to test, but obviously you'd have to be able to tolerate having your SQL Server offline for about a day.

Comment: @Charlieface Good thoughts. I performed a malware check as I was starting to suspect that as well but it came back clean. I am not able to shut down my server for a day as it is production 24 hour access.

Comment: My next suspicion inspired by the checkpoint theory is the garbage collection "lazy writer". According to some rando on some random forum this type of error could happen if I my max ram was not high enough. So I increased my ram and am waiting to see what happens under load on Monday.

Comment: Actually even simpler, if you're able to shut down the service for just a few minutes, you really only need to do that when you notice the next CPU spike. If the spikes still holds then you know it's not related to your SQL Server instance.

Comment: I know you said "nor do we have any automated SQL tasks", but is there anything in the SQL Agent jobs list at all that you may have missed? This smells like a task someone set ages ago, forgot to document it, and now that you're getting busier the database is getting locked up.